# What would cause apache to redirect from a local IP to a remote IP address

Tags: apache, redirect, webserver, centos6

Here's a scenario that I can't figure out; I simply can't understand why an slightly oldish webserver (totally inactive/powered-off for 2y) is behaving this way.  I **MUST** be overlooking something quite simple.

Specifically, when i try to access an Apache instance on Centos 7 residing on my local network (192.168.2.XXX), the apache page responds just fine (Testing 1,2,3; Yay).  Watching the access logs on this simple request shows up fine.  On this same machine, I have four additional paths set up.  One for example is a locked down phpMyAdmin that is accessible only from an internal IP.  This route works fine, and the databases can be browsed, etc.  Yet, for the other route, such as a wordpress installation or a route to a Magento instance, the the request comes up on the access log (no error log entry), and then just sits there.  When the request finally times out, the URL in the browser changes to a new ip address (ABC.XXX.YYY.ZZZ), and then terminates any efforts.

Admittedly, the machine WAS originally configured to be outward facing, and my suspicion is that the IP to which the pages revert may have been the public IP last time the machine was alive.  the IP is no longer associated with the site, and the domain which was likely setup with that IP address, is also no longer active.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I may look at?  I have combed the httpd configurations and there is nothing resembling any such redirection address.  Could there be some DNS data that needs to be flushed?  A network configuration in sysconfig/ that I am overlooking?

Comment: Can you post your conf files? A trace of web exchange (F12 in your brower -> network) will be helpfull. Also, it may be good to look at: iptables configuration, httpd listening addresses, and specific hosts file in your machine

Answer (score 0):

It was nothing to do with my apache configuration.  Everything was related to the site urls that were embedded inside the wordpress and magento installations.  Upon finding and replacing all instances of the site IP address in some configuration tables, I was able to get both applications to respond properly.